Converting blocking code to reactive code when I'm constrained by a blocking library
I have a custom Kafka library that for business reasons I'm forced to use. My use case is to read each record from Kafka and save to a repository. The entry to my repository is a callback I write that implements something like
interface Listener<T> {
    Response apply(T val);
}

The library takes my listener, iterates over the ConsumerRecords<T> from Kafka, and away I go. I wanted to see if I could use a reactive repository in Spring Data to save everything. Something like
Response apply(T val) {

    myRepo.save(val)
       .subscribe()

...
    return response;

}

So far I've only tried calling subscribe on the returned value of the Repository.save, but I don't have a way to dispose of all of these Publishers
But I immediately run into questions:

I'm creating a Mono for every iteration within ConsumerRecords, but I'm never disposing of any of them. I can't actually tell when to dispose of each Mono so this sounds like it would just create a memory leak
I know for a fact that the library starts with the ConsumerRecords collection, so it seems like this should naturally be a Flux, but since my entry is the callback I can't figure out how to make this happen

What would be ideal is to have some way to declare a Flux an set it so that each payload passed in is added to the flux, then call MyRepository.saveAll(Flux vals) and return a flux I can dispose of later, but if I understand the Reactor guide, I can't just add something to an exising Flux.
Is this just a hopeless cause? If I alternatively just take the Mono instance that comes back from calling MyRepository.save(T), when do I call dispose on it?

What is the end goal? Btw, the suggested code is not reactive and just uses a reactive code in a non-reactive way, so it doesn't give you any advantage

The end goal is non-blocking calls to save to the repository. I could use a thread pool and achieve something similar, but I'm trying to comprehend this from a reactive programming paradigm. Can you tell me how it's not reactive if I don't block?

As mentioned in the answer, even if you do as a reactive code you still have nothing reactive, so it gives you nothing except the style of code. That's why I asked about the end goal. If the goal is to have the code in this style, it's one thing and can work as you suggested. If the goal is to optimize something (speed, memory, latency, buffer, whatever) then you have to rewrite other parts as well.

Do you need to write to the database from code? Kafka Connect is an alternative. Then you could rewrite your code to use Kafka Streams to convert messages in a format acceptable to the database

@IgorArtamonov when you say we have nothing reactive, what does this really mean? The kafka client calls poll either way does it not?

That would depend on the goal, what you want to do eventually. In general, it means you have to build a large part of the application with Reactor, and most importantly you would NOT have subscribe or block in your code, except your main method.

To convert callback/listener based code to reactive (not fully though, see warning section below), Reactor provides the Flux.create() and Flux.push() static methods.
They're almost equivalent, except that push only handles single-threaded data sources.
How they fit your case
With this, you can:

create a Flux of received Kafka message:
Flux<R> receiveRecords(KafkaConsumer<R> datasource) {
    return Flux.push(sink -> {
        Listener<R> reactiveBridge = record -> sink.next(record);
        datasource.addListener(reactiveBridge);
        sink.onDispose(datasource.removeListener(reactiveBridge));
    });
}


With this, you can return to the reactive paradigm, and flatMap the created flux to your repository:
Flux<R> savedRecords = receiveRecords(datasource)
    .flatMap(record -> reactiveRepo.save(record))



Warning
One of the main advantages of reactive paradigm is to be able to manage back-pressure, i.e. adapt the pace of the upstream flow of data to the capabilities of downstream processors.
Beware: in this mode, you lose this advantage. Back-pressure becomes difficult to handle, because your datasource pushes without restrictions. There's a variant of both create and push that allow you to customize flux behaviour on back-pressure, but it is limited to either fail the flux, drop some of the received values, or buffer received values without restrictions (which can lead to memory overflow error).
So, if your kafka consumer is very fast (which is likely to be the case), and your database insertions are slow, you might encounter problems that will be difficult to handle without dataloss.
You can try to tamper this problem using batches:
Flux<Long> savedBatchSizes = receiveRecords(datasource)
    .buffer(100, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    .flatMap(batch -> reactiveRepo.saveAll(batch).count())

But there's no strong guarantee here.

This is an interesting idea, but I have so many questions. What is that call to KafkaConsumer#addListener?
The repository is itself reactive, so do I need to flatMap in this case?
I don't even have a reference to the KafkaConsumer at this point, I have a single payload from a poll passed to my code, so the best I can do is a Mono.just call to make it reactive, but then I'm creating thousands of Mono just to call save on the reactive repository. Am I hosed?

The KafkaConsumer.addListener aim to represent your kafka library that takes your listener. Instead of calling your repository in the listener, it is used downstream the Flux.push(...). It allows to model kafka records as a Flux, to be able to use flux operators (chain record reception to reactive operations, cancel it, etc.).

In your question, you say: "What would be ideal is to have some way to declare a Flux an set it so that each payload passed in is added to the flux". This is exactly what Flux.push does.
